# What is the purpose of this command ls -l> /testA921/file

Tags: terminal

What is the purpose of this command `ls –l> /testA921/file`?

Answer (score 1):

`ls -l` is a list directory command, similar to the Microsoft command line command `DIR`

If you'd like a fuller description of the `ls` command and its options, one can typically view the manual page for it using the `man ls` command

the `> /testA91/file` part means redirect the output of the `ls -l` command to the file named `file` in the directory `/testA921`

`/testA921/file` is the full path name to that file.